# Invoke a model method within a rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

My question is very simple but I could not find a correct answer for it. I have a rake task which invokes a model method.

```
task :post do
    BufferPreference.post
end
```

It doesn't work and throws the error 
uninitialized constant BufferPreference

I tryied adding the following require:    require 'buffer_preferences' but I get the error 
no such file to load -- buffer_preference

My model is defined as follows:

```
class BufferPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
```

in the file buffer_preference.rb

Comment: You are talking about controller, but invokes `post` method on model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run controller action as a method from the controller, it is not good practice. Try to move your code, into a **`Model`**.

Try this:

```
task :post => :environment do
    BufferPreference.post
end
```

`BufferPreference.post` that means you should have `BufferPreference` model, with class method called `post`.